# How can I change my profile?

Tags: support, profile-page

Strangely, many people ask how to change the profile picture (which is trivial) but nobody seems to have a problem changing anything else in their account. However, I simply cannot find a link to change anything else in my account, be the **about me**, **website**, **e-mail** or whatever.

I remember having edited my profile not so long ago, but now I really can't find the link to do this again. Since then a feature "Network Profile" has been added which allows me to sync my profile. But shouldn't there be a big red button to allow setting up or editing the profile in the first place?

Comment: Go to your profile. You will see a small edit button on the right side opposite your user name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply click on your picture above in the top bar.

Then once the profile page loads, click edit :

> [image]

Comment: Ok, I **knew** it must be something simple. Must have to do with some strange events coming up ;-) But seriously, what is the *network profile* about then? Shoudn't that be the central place for editing the profile? I probably should ask a separate question to get this clarified.

Comment: @MikeLischke the Network profile is just a "portal" to all your accounts around the network, it's not really a standalone profile that you can edit. It's being synchronized with your oldest account.