# How can I change the website URL displayed on my Stack Exchange profile webpages?

Tags: support, profile-page, stack-exchange, meta, linked-accounts

In 2020, in a browser where I'm not logged in to Stack Exchange, I go to [my Meta user profile page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/626767/ray-woodcock). That page offers a Profile link at the top left and a Network Profile link at the top right. Below the Network Profile link, it offers a link to [my old blog](https://raywoodcockslatest.blogspot.com/). I want to change it to link to [my new blog](https://raywoodcockslatest.wordpress.com/) across all Stack Exchange sites. How can I do that?

In a browser where I am logged in to Meta, on [the Home page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) I click on my picture on the top bar. That opens [my Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/626767/ray-woodcock). This, too, has Profile and Network Profile links at top left and right corners, respectively. Clicking the Profile link takes me to a page that says, "Your *about me* is currently blank."

That suggests that the link to my old blog must be set by the Network Profile link. Clicking on that takes me to a page that lists my old blog's URL, but provides no apparent way to change it. There is an Update Profile Info link at the right, but clicking on that oddly opens a dialog offering to "Choose a site to copy profile information from."

[Mike Lischke asked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213557/how-can-i-change-my-profile) this question in 2013. The answer to his question was to use the Profile (not Network Profile) link > click the Edit link. The appearance (and, apparently, the functionality) of the page has changed since then. The Edit link has apparently been replaced by a "Click here to edit" link. The resulting Edit Your Profile page does not appear to offer a way to replace the displayed link to my old blog.

A response to Lischke says, "The Network profile is just a "portal" to all your accounts around the network, it's not really a standalone profile that you can edit. It's being synchronized with your oldest account." [An answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81345/626767) to another question seems to say that I can overrule that default behavior when I edit the profile on any one site: I should see an option to "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts."

Answer (score 4):

To edit your blog link:

1. When logged in, go to your Meta profile and press the <kbd>Edit profile and settings</kbd> link at the top.
   [image: edit profile and settings link]
2. Scroll past the **About Me** editor to the **Web Presence** section. Edit the **Website Link** field to your new blog link.
   [image]
3. Press <kbd>Save and copy changes to all public communities</kbd> to save.

To synchronize it with your network profile:

1. Go to your network profile.
2. Press "*Update profile info*"
   [image]
3. Choose any site from the dialog box and press <kbd>Copy</kbd>